# SMPP optional parameters

Tags: asynchronous, match, correlation, smpp

Good day guys!. I'm currently working on a system using JMS queues that send message over SMPP (using Logica SMPP library).

My problem is that I need to attach an internal id (that we manage within our system) to the message sequence id so that when in async mode I receive a response, the proper action can be taken for that particular message.

The first option I tried to implement was the use of optional parameters, as established for SMPP 3.4. I do not receive the optional parameters in the response (I've read that the response attaches the optional parameters depending on the provider).

A second approach was to keep  a mapping in memory for those messages until their response is received (it saturates the memory, so it is a no go).

Can anyone else think on a viable solution for correlating an internal system ID of a message to its sequence number within an asynchronous SMPP environment?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep a map of seq_nr - internal message id and delete from this map as soon you get an async response back from SMSC.
It should not saturate the memory as it will keep only inflight messages but you need to periodicaly iterate over the map and delete orphaned entries  (as sometimes you will not get an reponse back from smsc).